# Can I check my current food effect outside of a rest area?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

Is there a way to check my party's current food effect outside of stopping at a rest area and checking the cook menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can check your current meal effect outside of battle though the pause menu. Press X to open the pause menu, select Party Skills, then press R twice to view Meal Effects. From this screen you can also press Y to get a description of of what each meal effect does.

[image]